# JADE Raspberry to Raspberry Communication

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, agents-jade

In short I try to establisch a discussion between 2 agents which are in 2 differents raspberry Pi using ACLMessage.

To connect raspberry pi together I set there Ip to static and now I have trouble to send a message from an agent to other. Firstly I try to use MTP on one agent but I have an error when I setup the profile : `SEVERE: Error installing MTP`

Hope you can help me.

**CODE**

```
public void setup() {
   Runtime runtime = Runtime.instance();

   String host = "198.168.6.20"; //raspberry IP
   String port = "1099";
   String MTP_hostIP = "198.168.6.20";
   String MTP_Port = "45678";
   Profile profile = new ProfileImpl();
   profile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_HOST, host);
   profile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_PORT, port);
   profile.setParameter(Profile.MTPS, "jade.mtp.http.MessageTransportProtocol(http://"+MTP_hostIP+":"+MTP_Port+"/acc)");

   ContainerController container = runtime.createMainContainer(profile);
   try{
      AgentController armAgentController = container.createNewAgent("Arm","ManipulationContainer.ArmAgent",null);
      armAgentController.start();
   }

   addBehaviour(new taskManagment(getAID("Arm")));
```

Comment: Is this a complete exception? Do you try to change ports?

Comment: After many try I finally found that my problem was my IP adress that was the same as my card. Now I use 127.0.0.1 that work well.